# Probit and probability of being a member of a group

Tags: probability, logit, probit

I was wondering if there was a specific way to convert probit regression results into a probability that a test subject is a member of group 1 (vs group 0) if you break up the dependent variable into 2 groups (e.g. success vs. failure.) I know that for logistic regression you use the inverse logit of the sum of the coefficients * the subject's values + the constant but I am unaware of how to do it with probit.

I'm sure there is a way because Stata can check the model's ability to classify with estat classification. I primarily use R now for my data analysis, so if you know how to do this in R, I would appreciate your help even more (currently I use inv.logit from the boot package.)

Comment: You should use the standard normal CDF. The caret package includes the confusion matrix code.

Comment: Thanks Dimitriy. So, I would just use the pnorm function in R on the outcome of the logit regression to get the probability?

Comment: You would use `pnorm` on the sum of the *probit* constant and the *probit* coefficients multiplied by the subject's values.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped logit when I meant probit. Thanks